# Zimbra ZCS 8.6 no dkim signature

Tags: dkim, zimbra

I made DKIM configuration as mentioned in ZCS manual by running:

`/opt/zimbra/libexec/zmdkimkeyutil -a -d rush.zone`

Tested it:

`/opt/zimbra/opendkim/sbin/opendkim-testkey -d rush.zone -s {Domain Selector} -x /opt/zimbra/conf/opendkim.conf`

No errors till now. Restarted ZCS. And still no DKIM signature header in messages nor from mail sent via Webmail, neither from SMTP.

Let me know where should I look in to debug this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have some code to show?  What have you tried?

Comment: Added DKIM to Zimbra by running: `/opt/zimbra/libexec/zmdkimkeyutil -a -d rush.zone`

Tested it: `/opt/zimbra/opendkim/sbin/opendkim-testkey -d rush.zone -s {Domain Selector} -x /opt/zimbra/conf/opendkim.conf`

No errors till now. Restarted ZCS. And still no DKIM signature nor from mail sent via Webmail, neither from SMTP.

Comment: Editing the question to include those extra info might be helpful - and more visible - than in the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `127.0.0.1` at the end of `/opt/zimbra/conf/opendkim-localnets.conf.in` and do:

```
$ su - zimbra
$ zmcontrol restart
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer by Sergiu Bivol is working GREAT.

```
$ nano /opt/zimbra/conf/opendkim-localnets.conf.in
```

Your file will look simillar to :

```
  %%zimbraMtaMyNetworksPerLine%%
  127.0.0.1
```

Save the file and execute :

```
$ su zimbra
$ zmcontrol restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem. 2 things you should check:

1. Check the zimbra log /var/log/zimbra.log about opendkim.
2. Verify dkim private key on ldap

   /opt/zimbra/libexec/zmdkimkeyutil -q -d {domain}

Comment: Hi Jack, I have a lot of such records:
`Mar 18 10:14:38 CentOS-66-64-minimal opendkim[13258]: 36E0C1E13A5: localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1] not internal
Mar 18 10:14:38 CentOS-66-64-minimal opendkim[13258]: 36E0C1E13A5: not authenticated`